# CPU process hidden when opened task manager but running(Over exerting) when closed

Tags: windows, debugging, process, cpu, taskmanager

I am using windows 10 Home edition and my CPU seems to over heat. around 80~85 C.
When I try to see which process is using so much CPU in task manager, the CPU utilization suddenly drops. I believe the process cleverly hides itself when I open the task manager. Please help. I also add the respective screenshots.
On battery:
[image]
When plugged in (Monitoring using radeon software and task manager): You can clearly see the bump down after opening task manager
[image]
After closing task manager, the cpu is again over exerting itself.
[image]
Please help